# Does getting the "bad" ending in Far Cry 5 change the pause menu?

Tags: far-cry-5

I finished the game a little while back and earned the "good" ending in which you

> ...save your friends. Suddenly, several nuclear devices explode and you and Joseph seed flee to a bunker

This ending affects the pause menu in a way I find distracting and unrewarding. If I were to replay the game again and choose the alternate ending in which

> ...you betray your friends and ultimately kill them, but no nuclear devices explode

do the in-game changes that stem from the good ending repeat, affecting the main menu and pause menu, do these menus remain unchanged, or is there a different menu for this alternate ending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter what ending you choose. You will get the same main menu background:

[image]